# What is the best way to justify text so that It's aesthetically pleasing and readible?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, typography

What is the best way to adjust justified text(see image) so that it looks aesthatically pleasing. What is the best practice when adjusting the values in the justification settings?

[image: Justified text]

[image: Image 2 - Justification settings]

Comment: Can you please include some more information as to what you mean?

Comment: Is there a trick that always works? Why isn't it enabled by default, then, in just about all text processing software?

Answer (score 1):

The most readable English text is short lines of left justified, high contrast, sentence case, modern serif, properly kerned and leaded, 12pt or larger, short common words.

It goes down hill from there.

As far as looking nice, well that's a more complex answer, and highly subjective. It depends on what you like and what you're trying to convey and to whom.

I would always choose readability over style, and when it comes to style I consider it successful when the reader does not notice the font styling at all, they just get the message from the writing that you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

Justification is usually about the end product. You would find it difficult to read a newspaper that was justified left. Newspapers and magazines will have text columns justified left & right for readability. Books often are the same, but not always. A blog, shot story, or letter are fine justified left. I've worked for both large newspapers and magazines.

Comment: Isn't your justified newspaper columns only because then the column gutter can be as small as possible, and thus saving space? With enough gutter, left-aligned text works just as well in more than one column.

Comment: Column widths have changed over the years, getting wider, As far as I know, the industry did extensive research on readability. People read them in three ways; Overview of headlines & cells, gleaning of content with a centered focus, and word for word. Who is your audience?